# Computing Picard groups of arbitrary quadric hyperplane

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, line-bundles, picard-group

I know the Picard group of a smooth two dimensional quadric surface is $\mathbb Z^2$, but I am wondering if the computation can be generalized to higher dimension? In particular, is the Picard group of a $n$-dimensional smooth quadric hypersurface $\{\sum_{i=0}^{n+1}x_i^2=0\}\subset\mathbb P^{n+1}$ known?

Comment: Smooth hypersurfaces in projective spaces $\mathbb{P}^n$ with $n\geq 4$ has Picard  group $\mathbb{Z}$ generated by the hyperplane section.

Comment: .... this usually goes by the name "Lefschetz hyperplane section theorem". You can read about it in the book Lazarsfeld - Positivity in Algebraic Geometry I.

Comment: This also follows by very simple methods as well: the blowing up of a smooth quadric at a point equals the blowing up of projective space along a smooth quadric whose dimension is two less.

Comment: The nice comment of Jason, (project the quadric from a point of itself down one dimension), also explains why the theorem fails precisely for surfaces: smooth quadrics are reducible precisely in dimension zero!